# How do I insert an error command in my text to speech program?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, speech-to-text, gtts

I have a STT combined with a TTS program that runs on a raspberry pi. I was able to put a command that says "error" when the recognizer fails to detect a word. We assigned words as command to save mp3 files and then play them. How do I add an additional "error" command when our recognizer successfully read a word that is not in our commands? My program looks like these.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import sys                                                                                                                                                                                                           
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
from gtts import gTTS
import os
import playsound
from pygame import mixer
import traceback

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(2 ,GPIO.IN)
prev_input = 1


mixer.init()
listener = sr.Recognizer()
engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty("voices")
rate = engine.getProperty("rate")
engine.setProperty("rate", 180)



def talk(text):
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()


while True:
        input = GPIO.input(2)

        if ((not prev_input) and input):
            try:

                with sr.Microphone() as source:
                    print('You can speak now')
                    talk("You can speak now")
                    listener.phrase_threshold = 2
                    audio = listener.listen(source, 8)
                    command = listener.recognize_google(audio)
                    text = command
                    speech = gTTS(text=text, lang="en", slow=False, )
                    speech.save("texttospeech.mp3")
                print(command)

                if command == command:
                        if command == "hello":
                            print("good morning")
                            tts = gTTS(text="good morning", lang="en")
                            filename="goodmorning.mp3"
                            tts.save("goodmorning.mp3")
                            mixer.music.load("goodmorning.mp3")
                            mixer.music.play()
                            
                        if command == "hey":
                            print("hi there")
                            tts = gTTS(text="hi there", lang="en")
                            filename="hithere.mp3"
                            tts.save("hithere.mp3")
                            mixer.music.load("hithere.mp3")
                            mixer.music.play()

                        if command == "yes":
                            print("no")
                            tts = gTTS(text="no", lang="en")
                            filename="no.mp3"
                            tts.save("no.mp3")
                            mixer.music.load("no.mp3")
                            mixer.music.play()


            except Exception:
                traceback.print_exc()
                tts = gTTS(text="error", lang="en")
                filename = "error.mp3"
                tts.save("error.mp3")
                mixer.music.load("error.mp3")
                mixer.music.play()


        prev_input = input

        time.sleep(.05)`
```

As you can see, there are only 3 commands in the program, I want all other readings to prompt an "error" command similar to the command in my except block. I have tried using elif on all the commands but it continuously played the error mp3 file.

Answer (score 2):

Use if elif else

```
    if command == "hello":
    print("good morning")
    tts = gTTS(text="good morning", lang="en")
    filename="goodmorning.mp3"
    tts.save("goodmorning.mp3")
    mixer.music.load("goodmorning.mp3")
    mixer.music.play()
elif command == "hey":
    print("hi there")
    tts = gTTS(text="hi there", lang="en")
    filename="hithere.mp3"
    tts.save("hithere.mp3")
    mixer.music.load("hithere.mp3")
    mixer.music.play()
elif command == "yes":
    print("no")
    tts = gTTS(text="no", lang="en")
    filename="no.mp3"
    tts.save("no.mp3")
    mixer.music.load("no.mp3")
    mixer.music.play()
else:
    print("error")
```